# how get arraylist from data json url android studio

Tags: java, android, json

I am new in android and i try to get weather information via yahoo weather service , the app is working fine weather JSONObject but not working with the array list. I make some try but not working.

my code

```
public void serviceSuccess(Channel channel, JSONObject data) {
    loadingDialog.hide();

    Condition condition = channel.getItem().getCondition();
    Units units = channel.getUnits();
    Condition[] forecast = channel.getItem().getForecast();

    int weatherIconImageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("icon_" + condition.getCode(), "drawable", getPackageName());

    weatherIconImageView.setImageResource(weatherIconImageResource);
    temperatureTextView.setText(getString(R.string.temperature_output, condition.getTemperature(), units.getTemperature()));
    conditionTextView.setText(condition.getDay());
    condition = new Condition();
    condition.populate(data.optJSONObject("condition"));
    JSONArray forecastData = data.optJSONArray("forecast");

    forecast = new Condition[forecastData.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < forecastData.length(); i++) {
        forecast[i] = new Condition();
        try {
            forecast[i].populate(forecastData.getJSONObject(i));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

[json](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=0e772ab9dd718a01c9a799858b7ae78e) if a possible any full answer please

Comment: Do you have any stack traces? Why isn't it working? What's the behavior you're seeing and what is the behavior you expected?

Comment: actually am new in android studio , so do you would like to take look via teamvid on my code ?